# Python download file with original filename

Tags: python

I had use Python and beautiful soup to detect links from a website, now I want to download the image files from detected url and store them to store in a specific folder, what would be the most easiest way do so?

The code I develop so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  # HTML data structure
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq  # Web client
from PIL import Image
import requests
my_url = "https://abc/videos/vod/movies/actress/letter=a/sort=popular/page=1/"

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html=uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

for div in page_soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'main'}):
    for ul in div.findAll('ul'):
        for li in ul.findAll('li'):
            for img in li.findAll('img', alt=True):
                link=img['src']
```

The url links detected:

```
https://abcde/mono/actjpgs/abb1.jpg
https://abcde/mono/actjpgs/t31sw.jpg
https://abcde/mono/actjpgs/beaas.jpg
```

End result file name:

```
abb1.jpg
t31sw.jpg
beaas.jpg
```

Comment: Did you try putting, for example, `python requests download file` into a search engine?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Karl suggested a quick google search would have told you this but since I am being helpful in my early SO career I will try and do it for you.

```
import requests

link = your/example/link.jpg

# Get image and file name
r = requests.get(link, allow_redirects=True) 
fname = link.split('/')[-1]

# save the file
open(fname, 'wb').write(r.content)
```

I have not tested this code.

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
import shutil
from urllib.parse import urlparse

# get filename from URL
url = "https://abcde/mono/actjpgs/abb1.jpg"
url_parsed = urlparse(url)
filename = os.path.basename(url_parsed.path)    # will contain abb1.jpg 

# download file
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(filename, 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
```